# It Is possible to get java objects directly from Encoded String rather than converting Encoded String into File and then read the file?

Tags: java, base64, decode, encode, decoder

My Requirement :

1. I am receiving encoded String from one of my REST Api Now this encoded string need to be decode using Base64 decoder .
2. As This contain files I need to decode like Base64 to File, this can happen using below link, If I just copy paste below encoded string into below link, it gives me files to download
3. https://base64.guru/converter/decode/file
4. Now My Question, Is it possible to convert below encoded String to Java Object directly somehow rather converting them into file.

- My Ultimate goal is to bring data from encoded string.

-----Right now the flow is-------

EncodedString ==> Convert Base 64 to CSV File and download the files ==> Read CSV File using Java ==>> Data available In Java Object

----Can below possible ?-------

EncodedString ==> Decode and Convert File into Java Object ==>> Data available In Java Object

### Encoded String :

What I have tried

```
package com.oracleerp;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Zip {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        convertZipAndDownload();
    }

    private static void convertZipAndDownload() throws IOException {
        try {
            String str1 = "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";
            byte[] decodedImg = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            Path destinationFile = Paths.get("/Users/as.asd/Documents/zip", "myImage1.zip");
            Files.write(destinationFile, decodedImg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error :" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine to download zip, but I want to do all this operation in Memory without doing any downloading stuff

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily decode Base64 data to `byte[]` in Java using [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.html) like this:

```
String myBase64String = ...;
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(myBase64String);
```

Note that you might need to replace `getDecoder()` with either `getMimeDecoder()` or `getUrlDecoder()`, depending on what type of Base64 encoding your string used.

Then if you need some kind of processing that needs that data as an input you can easily create an `InputStream` that provides that data using an `ByteArrayInputStream`:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded);
```

If however, your processing code insists on taking a `File` object, then you'll need to modify that code to accept an `InputStream` directly (usually that's easy, because most of those methods simply create a `FileInputStream` and read that, just skip that step and used the passed-in `InputStream` instead).

Comment: Thanks Joachim Sauer.! 

I have tried below, please check in comments could advice for next step. 
Please note my decoded string will produce zip file.

Comment: I have updated Question with Programm
I want to read zip file in memory 
byte[] ==> Zip File ==> extract it ==> again extract 2 zip inside this => read CSV file from both of them. 

All this I want to perform this in memory without downloading files.

Comment: Just create a [`ZipInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) from `in` and continue unzipping the content like you would from a file, there's no difference to doing it from a file after that step.